# WPF Linq a collection to include or exclude items

Tags: c#, wpf, linq

I'm not really sure how to word the title. This is what I'm looking for if it's possible in a linq statement.

I have 3 comboboxes that the user can select a value. On the SelectionChanged event of each combobox will filter out an observablecollection that would only populate another collection based on the values. The comboboxes contains a blank at the top for the user to select not to apply the filter on that column.

Is there a simple way to use linq to do this?

Hope I explained that clear enough.

Comment: Sure, linq can help you. Are combos use different SelectionChanged hanlder or the same?

Comment: Would seem to make more sense to have them all fire the same event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You xaml might be like this:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cmb1" SelectionChanged="Selector_OnSelectionChanged">
<ComboBox x:Name="cmb2" SelectionChanged="Selector_OnSelectionChanged">
<ComboBox x:Name="cmb3" SelectionChanged="Selector_OnSelectionChanged">
```

And code of the handler:

```
var someCollection = new List<int>(); // some your collection

// stubs
Expression<Func<int, bool>> predicate1 = (x) => true;
Expression<Func<int, bool>> predicate2 = (x) => true;
Expression<Func<int, bool>> predicate3 = (x) => true;

// real predicates
if (cmb1.SelectedIndex >= 0)
    predicate1 = (x) => x == (int)cmb1.SelectedValue;
if (cmb2.SelectedIndex >= 0)
    predicate2 = (x) => x == (int)cmb2.SelectedValue;
if (cmb3.SelectedIndex >= 0)
    predicate3 = (x) => x == (int)cmb3.SelectedValue;

// eval and out
lstBox.Items = someCollection.Where(predicate1)
                             .Where(predicate2)
                             .Where(predicate3)
                             .ToList();
```

I wrote this deatailed in order to make more clear.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see your code so maybe i'm wrong but you can use this approach,every SelectionChanged event use this code:

```
       yourCollection = (from c in yourCollection
        where c.... (your conditions)
            select c).ToList();
```

Edit:

To handle all changes with one method:

```
private void UpdateCollection(ComboBox comboBox)
    {
        if (comboBox.Text != "")
        {
            values = (from c in yourCollection
                               where c.... (your conditions)
                                  select c).ToList();
        }

    }
```

and then call it from each SelectionChanged event

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UpdateCollection(comboBox1);
    }
```

Comment: I don't currently have anything written to handle it. I'm not sure how to write the statement that if a value is blank it's not included in the statement

Comment: you can simply use if statement for this,and if you can handle all changes in one method i will update my code i hope it will help you